# Bullets Spawning in same direction

Tags: xna, c#, physics

I'm using XNA to make a Bullet Hell Shooter game, and I'm running into some troubles when I try to change the direction in which the bullets move. Been trying to debug for awhile, but haven't gotten anywhere.

The effect that I am trying to have is

I've included all code that might have any dealing with the code.

Custom Box class(really only used for holding the Rectangle and Velocity)

```
    class Box
    {
        public Rectangle rect;
        public Vector2 velo;
        public Box()
        {
            rect = new Rectangle();
        }

        public Box(Rectangle r, Vector2 v)
        {
            rect = r;
            velo = v;
        }
    }
```

Global Declaration:

```
    List<Box> bullets;
    List<int> bulletType;
```

Bullet Logic:

```
    public void bulletStuff()
    {
        if (bullets.Count > 100)
        {
            while (bullets.Count > 99)
            {
                bullets.RemoveAt(0);
                bulletType.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        {
            bullets[i].rect.Y -= (int)bullets[i].velo.Y;
            bullets[i].rect.X += (int)bullets[i].velo.X;

            if (bullets[i].rect.Y < 0)
            {
                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Collision w/ Enemy & Enemy Logic(Also a Box)

```
        public void enemyStuff()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < enemyRects.Count; i++)
            {
                enemyRects[i].rect.Y += (int)enemyRects[i].velo.Y;
                enemyRects[i].rect.X += (int)enemyRects[i].velo.X;

                if (enemyRects[i].rect.Y >= 800)
                {
                    enemyRects.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }

                if (enemyRects[i].rect.Intersects(playerRect))
                {
                    playerHealth--;
                    enemyRects.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < bullets.Count; j++)
                {
                    if(bullets[j].rect.Intersects(enemyRects[i].rect))
                    {
                        bullets.RemoveAt(j);
                        bulletType.RemoveAt(j);
                        enemyHealth[i]--;
                    }
                }

                if (enemyHealth[i] <= 0)
                {
                    enemyRects.RemoveAt(i);
                    enemyHealth.RemoveAt(i);
                    enemiesKilled++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Update Method

```
            if ((curKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && !preKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) || (curMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && preMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed))
            {//Spawning the Elements
                Box Temp;
                if (level == 0)
                {
                    Temp = new Box();
                    Temp.rect = new Rectangle(playerRect.X + (playerRect.Width / 2) - 2, playerRect.Y - (playerRect.Height / 2), 5, 5);
                    Temp.velo = new Vector2(0, 10);
                    bullets.Add(Temp);
                    bulletType.Add(0);
                }
                else if (level == 1)
                {
                    Temp = new Box();
                    Temp.rect = new Rectangle(playerRect.X + (playerRect.Width / 2) - 2, playerRect.Y - (playerRect.Height / 2), 10, 10);
                    Temp.velo = new Vector2(-2, 10);
                    bullets.Add(Temp);
                    bulletType.Add(1);
                    Temp.velo = new Vector2(2, 10);
                    bullets.Add(Temp);
                    bulletType.Add(2);
                }
                else if (level == 2)
                {
                    Temp = new Box();
                    Temp.rect = new Rectangle(playerRect.X + (playerRect.Width / 2) - 2, playerRect.Y - (playerRect.Height / 2), 10, 10);
                    Temp.velo = new Vector2(-2, 10);
                    bullets.Add(Temp);
                    bulletType.Add(1);
                    Temp.velo = new Vector2(2, 10);
                    bullets.Add(Temp);
                    bulletType.Add(2);
                }
                else
                {
                    Temp = new Box();
                    Temp.rect = new Rectangle(playerRect.X + (playerRect.Width / 2) - 2, playerRect.Y - (playerRect.Height / 2), 10, 10);
                    Temp.velo = new Vector2(-2, 10);
                    bullets.Add(Temp);
                    bulletType.Add(1);
                    Temp.velo = new Vector2(2, 10);
                    bullets.Add(Temp);
                    bulletType.Add(2);
                }

            }

            playerRect.X = curMouseState.X - playerRect.Width / 2;
            playerRect.Y = curMouseState.Y - playerRect.Height / 2;

            levelStuff();
            bulletStuff();
            enemyStuff();

            if (playerHealth == 0)
            {
                ScreenManager.Instance.addScreen(new TitleScreen(myGame)); //Exits to menu
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

What is occurring currently is this:

[image]

As you can see, it is spawning both new bullets(which are supposed to go opposite of each other) moving in the same direction.

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken already?

Comment: @Byte56
I've already redone the spawning code, as well as tried to figure out where the second bullet spawned is. I discovered that they are spawning in the exact same place, although, they are not moving in the same direction. In the picture I drew the bullets by number, but they overlap, thus I'm led to believe that the vaie of "Temp" when spawning bullets does not change after I reassign the value of it's X velocity to 2, instead of -2.

Comment: Even though you're adding the bullet to the list, if you modify it after that, you're still modifying the original. So from the looks of it, you're adding two bullets every time both of type two and with a velocity of (2, 10). You have to create a *new* bullet and modify its value if you want to have different bullets. BTW, I'm voting to close this as too localized. This isn't the place for people to debug your code for you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Byte56 , it worked just as you said. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to comment a little bit of your code:

```
Temp = new Box(); //create a new box
Temp.rect = new Rectangle(playerRect.X + (playerRect.Width / 2) - 2,
  playerRect.Y - (playerRect.Height / 2), 10, 10); //set its size and position
Temp.velo = new Vector2(-2, 10); //set its velocity to (-2, 10)
bullets.Add(Temp); //add it to the bullets list
bulletType.Add(1); //add a type...
Temp.velo = new Vector2(2, 10); //now change its velocity (this is still accessing the object stored in the list).
bullets.Add(Temp); //add it AGAIN to the list. Now we have two bullets with a velocity of (2, 10)
bulletType.Add(2); //add a type.
```